# How to print filename into itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-line

I have multiple files(100-1000) in foo dir. I want to append each filename to its own content. I think the for loop should resolve appending a random string to for each file,

```
for f in *; do printf "%10s \n" $(shuf -i 50-100 -n 50 -r) >> $f; done
```

How can I append filename to all this shuffled numbers, directly concatanate them?

```
for f in *; do printf "%10s \n" $f $(shuf -i 50-100 -n 50 -r) >> $f; done
```

result in file 5:

```
5
67
89
69
...
```

expected result:

```
567
589
569
...
```

Comment: You want to append each filename, but you talk about appending random strings, too? What are you trying to do exactly? Can you show what the sample input and output would be for a single file? If the files don't affect each other, then just forget about the loop for now, it only distracts from the main point. If the files do affect each other, then how?

Comment: You are right, the main point is how can I repeat a variable with count of the shuf -n argument. I am trying to write a code that applies hundreds of files so for loop inescapable I think.

Comment: You already got it - simply store the result from `shuf` in a variable and use that twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, if I get it right, you want to prefix a fixed string to all numbers printed by `shuf`. If so, just add that string to the start of the `printf` format string:

```
$ printf "x%10s\n" $(shuf -i 50-100 -n 3 -r)
x        71
x        70
x        92
```

Change the `%10s` to `%s` get them back to back without the whitespace. Similarly, you can use the loop variable instead:

```
$ for f in 1 2 3; do printf "$f%s\n" $(shuf -i 50-100 -n 2 -r); done
151
197
268
256
364
354
```

Add the `>> "$f"` to redirect to files.

Note that since the fixed part is part of the format string here, any `%` signs and backslashes would be interpreted by `printf`.

Comment: `printf "%s%s\n" "$f" "$(shuf ...)"` would be better: if the filename happens to contain a `%`, you'll be protected this way.

Comment: @glennjackman, indeed, except that it doesn't work. :) You can't quote the output of `shuf` as this relies on wordsplitting it. Even then, you'd get the fixed part only once, try something like `printf "%s %s\n" xx $(shuf -i 50-100 -n 4 -r)`.

Comment: We could use something like `for f in *; do for n in $(shuf ...); do printf "%s%s\n" "$f" "$n"; done; done`

Answer (score 6):

Store result of `shuf` into a bash array, then use substitution in the parameter expansion to prepend `$f`:

```
mapfile -t shuf < <(shuf -i 50-100 -n 50)
printf '%10s \n' "${shuf[@]/#/"$f"}" >>"$f"
```

---

With zsh, use `^` parameter expansion:

```
printf '%10s \n' "$f${(f)^"$(shuf -i 50-100 -n 50)"}" >> "$f"
```